# My handlebars loop definition is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, express, handlebars.js

I need a handlebars version of my for loop. So I registered a helper to make an incremental, classic for loop structure. My problem is I can't use variables inside that handlebars front-end notation. Everything works fine with my `ifCond` registered helper, but my for loop is not working. `iterator`, `page` and `endingLink` are variables which are rendering from a controller.js file. I mean, these variables are viable outside of the `for` loop, but I can't use their values inside the loop. For example:

> `<a class="selectedLink" href="/?page={{iterator}}">{{iterator}}</a>`

href or innerHTML value of the  tag equals to nothing. Any ideas?

**This is my code :**

```
hbs.registerHelper('for', function(from, to, incr, block) {
    let accum = '';
    for(var i = from; i <= to; i += incr)
        accum += block.fn(i);
     

    return accum;
});
```

**Front-end implementation**

```
{{#ifCond page '>' 1 }}<a href="/?page={{page}}">Before</a>{{/ifCond}}


            {{#for iterator endingLink iteratorInc}}


            {{#ifCond iterator '===' page}}

            <a class="selectedLink" href="/?page={{iterator}}">{{iterator}}</a>


            {{/ifCond}}

            <a href="/?page={{iterator}}">{{iterator}}</a>


            {{/for}}
            {{#ifCond page '<' numberOfPages }}<a href="/?page={{page}}">After</a>{{/ifCond}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the problem, I will start with a simplified version of your template:

```
{{#for iterator endingLink iteratorInc}}
  {{log iterator}}
{{/for}}
```

In this simplified template, we are using your `for` block helper. The body of the block is simply `{{log iterator}}` which will use the Handlebars built-in `log` [helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#log) to log the value of `iterator`.

This will log `undefined` for each iteration between the `from` and `to` arguments to our `for` helper.

This is because there is no `iterator` variable defined within the context of our block. The context for the block is determined by the argument passed to the invocation of `block.fn` within our `for` helper. In this case, the value is `i` - the current iteration of our for loop.

This means that the execution context for the block has a single value, a number. We can access this value with the `this` keyword. Our template becomes:

```
{{#for iterator endingLink iteratorInc}}
  {{log this}}
{{/for}}
```

Which now logs a sequence of numbers, for example: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

This is good, but when we transfer this to your actual block body implementation, we still have a problem.

The `{{#ifCond iterator '===' page}}` will never be met because there is no `page` in our block context and so it is always `undefined`. We need to get the `page` value from the parent context.

Fortunately, Handlebars [provides a way](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context) for us to "step up" to a higher context level to grab a value: `../`. Therefore, the expression we need in our template is: `../page`.

Finally, the non-`selectedLink` anchor (`<a href="/?page={{this}}">{{this}}</a>`) is going to render for each iteration of our loop, causing a duplicate of the selected page link. We would want to use an `{{else}}` to prevent the duplication.

Our template becomes:

```
{{#for iterator endingLink iteratorInc}}
  {{#ifCond this '===' page}}
    <a class="selectedLink" href="/?page={{this}}">{{this}}</a>
  {{else}}
    <a href="/?page={{this}}">{{this}}</a>
  {{/ifCond}}
{{/for}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/gw2uqhor/) for reference.